# How to scroll automatically within a Tkinter message window

Tags: python, qt, qt4, tkinter, ipython

I wrote the following class for producing "monitoring" output within an extra window.

1. Unfortunately it doesn't scroll automatically down to the most recent line. What is wrong?
2. As I also have problems with Tkinter and ipython: how would an equivalent implementation with qt4 look like?

Here is the code:

```
import Tkinter
class Monitor(object):
  @classmethod
  def write(cls, s):
    try:
      cls.text.insert(Tkinter.END, str(s) + "\n")
      cls.text.update()
    except Tkinter.TclError, e:
      print str(s)
  mw = Tkinter.Tk()
  mw.title("Message Window by my Software")
  text = Tkinter.Text(mw, width = 80, height = 10)
  text.pack()
```

Usage:

```
Monitor.write("Hello World!")
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Add a statement `cls.text.see(Tkinter.END)` right after the one calling insert.

Comment: Consider usability when doing this. For example, if the user has scrolled back up from the bottom to look at something  you don't want to automatically scroll.

Comment: "Python: Scroll a ScrolledText automatically to the end if the user is not scrolling manually" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51781247/python-scroll-a-scrolledtext-automatically-to-the-end-if-the-user-is-not-scroll

Answer (score 6):

To those who might want to try binding:

```
def callback():
    text.see(END)
    text.edit_modified(0)
text.bind('<<Modified>>', callback)
```

Just be careful. As @BryanOakley pointed out, the Modified virtual event is only called once until it is reset. Consider below:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def showEnd(event):
    text.see(tk.END)
    text.edit_modified(0) #IMPORTANT - or <<Modified>> will not be called later.

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root= tk.Tk()

    text=tk.Text(root, wrap=tk.WORD, height=5)
    text.insert(tk.END, "Can\nThis\nShow\nThe\nEnd\nor\nam\nI\nmissing\nsomething")
    text.edit_modified(0) #IMPORTANT - or <<Modified>> will not be called later.
    text.pack()
    text.bind('<<Modified>>',showEnd)

    button=tk.Button(text='Show End',command = lambda : text.see(tk.END))
    button.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you say it's broken? Is this a documented bug?

Comment: Are you aware that `<<Modified>>` only fires once the first time the window transitions from not-modified to modified? You won't get the event again until you clear that flag with `.edit_modified(True)`.

Comment: Figures: [tkdocs](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html) doesn't explain this, nor [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm), but [tcl.tk](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/text.htm#M72) does if you read closely. Adjusting answer above, thanks! Btw, it's `.edit_modified(False)`