# Python: Scroll a ScrolledText automatically to the end if the user is not scrolling manually

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I made my `ScrolledText` **scroll automatically** to the end, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30671211/1792858).

Now I'd like to scroll automatically **only if** the user is **not scrolling manually**.

I was looking for something like this: `self.text.offsetBottom` *(see my comment in the code below)*, but couldn't find it yet.

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
import time
from Tkinter import *
import ScrolledText

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.text = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(self, height=6, width=40)
        self.text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.add_timestamp()

    def add_timestamp(self):
        self.text.insert("end", time.ctime() + "\n")

        """ -----> HERE <----- """         
        # if self.text.offsetBottom > 0:
        self.text.see("end")
        self.after(1000, self.add_timestamp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root =Tk()
    frame = Example(root)
    frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What would you like `text.offsetBottom` to return?

Comment: @Goyo e.g. `0` if there is no offset. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `yview()` method to see if the widget is fully scrolled down. `yview()` returns a 2-tuple with the top and bottom of the visible part relative to the total size. So if the widget is fully scrolled down, the second number should be `1.0`.

We can use this to only scroll if the widget was fully scrolled down before the insert happened:

```
def add_timestamp(self):
    fully_scrolled_down = self.text.yview()[1] == 1.0
    self.text.insert("end", time.ctime() + "\n")
    if fully_scrolled_down:
        self.text.see("end")
    self.after(1000, self.add_timestamp)
```

---

Another option is to check whether the last character is currently visible or not using

```
visible = self.text.bbox("end-1c")
```

From [effbot](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112033110/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.bbox-method), we can read that this method gives a 4-tuple if the character is visible, or `None` if the character is not visible:

> **bbox(index)**
> Calculates the bounding box for the given character.
>
> This method only works if the text widget is updated. To make sure this is the case, you can call the update_idletasks method first.
>
> *index*
> Character index.
> Returns:
> A 4-tuple (x, y, width, height), or None, if the character is not visible.

We can use this to only scroll if the last character was visible before the insert happened:

```
def add_timestamp(self):
    last_char_visible= self.text.bbox("end-1c")
    self.text.insert("end", time.ctime() + "\n")
    if last_char_visible:
        self.text.see("end")
    self.after(1000, self.add_timestamp)
```