# Tkinter: autoscroll to the bottom when user is not scrolling

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have made a small tkinter application, that receives data from the serial port and displays them on a ScrolledText frame.

I have manaded to make the frame autoscroll down to the end, when new data appears.

There is a problem however. If the user wants to see a particular value the autoscrolling option will make him lose it.
This is why i want to make it autoscroll, only when the user is not scrolling manually.

I based my code on this answer:
[Python: Scroll a ScrolledText automatically to the end if the user is not scrolling manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51781247/python-scroll-a-scrolledtext-automatically-to-the-end-if-the-user-is-not-scroll)

This is my code:

```
def readSerial():
    global val1
    fully_scrolled_down = scrollbar.yview()[1] == 1.0
    ser_bytes = ser.readline()
    ser_bytes = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
    val1 = ser_bytes
    scrollbar.insert("end", val1)
    if fully_scrolled_down:
        scrollbar.see("end") #autoscroll to the end of the scrollbar
```

However, this is not working. This code just constantly autoscrolls down, regardless of the use is manually scrolling up.

UPDATE: This is the code from the scrolledText frame:

```
frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff') #remove color later
frame2.place(relx=0, rely=0.1, relheight=1, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')

# make a scrollbar
scrollbar = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(frame2)
scrollbar.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=0.9, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')
```

UPDATE 2:
Full code

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import serial.tools.list_ports
from tkinter import scrolledtext 
import time
import serial
import threading
import continuous_threading


#to be used on our canvas
HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH = 800

#hardcoded baud rate
baudRate = 9600

ser = serial.Serial('COM16', baudRate)
val1 = 0

def readSerial():
    global val1
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51781247/python-scroll-a-scrolledtext-automatically-to-the-end-if-the-user-is-not-scroll
    fully_scrolled_down = scrollbar.yview()[1] == 1.0 #remove for ayutoscroll when not afafa
    ser_bytes = ser.readline()
    ser_bytes = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
    val1 = ser_bytes
    scrollbar.insert("end", val1)
    if fully_scrolled_down: #remove for ayutoscroll when not afafa
        scrollbar.see("end") #autoscroll to the end of the scrollbar


t1 = continuous_threading.PeriodicThread(0.1, readSerial)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# --- main ---
root = tk.Tk() #here we create our tkinter window
root.title("Sensor Interface")


#we use canvas as a placeholder, to get our initial screen size (we have defined HEIGHT and WIDTH)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

# --- frame 2 ---
frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff') #remove color later
frame2.place(relx=0, rely=0.1, relheight=1, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')

# make a scrollbar
scrollbar = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(frame2)
scrollbar.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=0.9, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')
# --- frame 2 ---
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------





t1.daemon=True
t1.start()

root.mainloop() #here we run our app
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you looked at what `scrollbar.yview()[1]` returns, to see if it is what you expect at all times?

Comment: You are calling `yview` and `insert` and `see` on something named `scrollbar` -- is `scrollbar` a scrollbar, or is it a text widget?

Comment: Please create a working [mcve]. When I mocked up an app an added your `readSerial` function as-is, it worked just fine.

Comment: @BryanOakley i updated the question with the full code.

Comment: The example would be better if it didn't have to read from an actual serial device. You should add a simulated serial port, otherwise very few people will be able to run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yview()[1]` does not consistently return `1.0` since your text widget is constantly being updated. Instead of using `scrolledtext` module you can create one yourself, that way you have a control over the `Scrollbar`'s attributes. Check the below example.

```py
from tkinter import *
import random

def foo():
    val=random.randint(1000,9999)
    label.config(text=val)
    text.insert(END,f"{val}\n")
    if vsb.get()[1]==1.0:
        text.see(END)
    root.after(200,foo)

root=Tk()

label=Label(root)
label.pack()
text_frame=Frame(root)
text_frame.pack()
text=Text(text_frame)
text.pack(side='left')
vsb=Scrollbar(text_frame)
vsb.pack(side='left',fill='y')
text.config(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
vsb.config(command=text.yview)

foo()

root.mainloop()
```

`get` method of `Scrollbar` return a tuple of `(top,bottom)` coordinates accurately and you can make use of this.

Comment: Thank you. But since this changes code a lot, and i have two active problems, each requiring changes in code, i will try to solve the periodical running error first, before i jump to this one.

Comment: Thank you! Your code worked. I made a small change as it was difficult to place the scrollbar to the bottom, so that the autoscroll continues (as the scrollbar was constantly moving up). So from this line if vsb.get()[1]==1.0, i changed 1.0 to 0.9. A thousand thanks!